# Cannot allocate a pointer using `std::make_shared`

Tags: c++, c++14

I have some trouble understanding what is the difference in terms of creating a `new` object of an abstract class using `std::make_shared` and `std::shared_ptr`? 
So in my specific case, I am not able to use this:

```
p_network_connection_ = std::make_shared<awsiotsdk::NetworkConnection> (awsiotsdk::ConfigCommon::endpoint_);
```

But able to do this:

```
p_network_connection_ = std::shared_ptr<awsiotsdk::NetworkConnection>(new awsiotsdk::network::WebSocketConnection(awsiotsdk::ConfigCommon::endpoint_);
```

How come? As if I try the first method (using `std::make_shared`), I get this error:

```
 error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘awsiotsdk::NetworkConnection’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

Comment: `std::make_shared<wsiotsdk::network::WebSocketConnection>`

Comment: @Raxvan Ok... So I was trying to make an object from the Abstract class whereas the second method was only stating the type (which is an abstract class) but creates an object of the derived class...

Comment: How is the first version supposed to guess which concrete derived type you want? All you told it was the abstract base type ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhm it looks like you are creating instances of different classes. In your first example, you attempt to create an instance of `awsiotsdk::NetworkConnection` class. Given the error, I can assume that it is an abstract class - and thus an instance of this can not be created.
In your second example you are creating an instance of `new awsiotsdk::network::WebSocketConnection` class. Given that it 'works' for you - it is not an abstruct class :)

So why not to try:

```cpp
p_network_connection_ = std::make_shared<awsiotsdk::network::WebSocketConnection> (awsiotsdk::ConfigCommon::endpoint_);
```